# Improving Program Efficiency

Tags: java, performance, runtime

```
public class cowcode {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long index = 1000000
    String line = HELLO

    boolean found = false;
    if (index <= line.length())
        found = true;

    while (!found) {
        line += buildString(line);
        if (index <= line.length())
            found = true;
    }

    if (found)
        System.out.println("" + charAt(line, index-1));
}

public static String buildString(String str){
    String temp = "" + str.charAt(str.length()-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i ++){
        temp += str.charAt(i);
    }
    return temp;
}

public static String charAt(String line, long index){
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i ++){
        if (i == index)
            return line.charAt(i) + "";
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

Hey! The code above works perfectly fine. However the only problem is runtime.

The objective of this program is to build a string from "HELLO" (which will eventually have the length of at least size index). This is done by rotating the String to the right ("HELLO" --> "HELLOOHELL", and concatenating the original String and the rotated version together. This process will not stop until the index that the program is looking for is found in the String. (so in this example, the String will become "HELLOOHELLLHELLOOHEL" after going through the loop twice).

Do you guys see anything that could be eliminated/shortened to improve runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the index without actually building the string. The right half of the composite string it rotated, the left one is not. If You have index in the left half of the string, You can just throw away the right half. Hence You simplified the situation. If You have index in the right half, You can transform it to index in the left half. You just need to undo rotation of the string in the right half. So You rotate the index left by one character. Now You can substract legth of half of the string and You have index in the left half of the string. This situation is already described above. So You shorten the string and start again at the beginning. In the end You end up with the string, that is not composed. It is the original string. Now You can address the characters directly with the index as it is now in range of the string.

```
index = 1000000 - 1;
line = "HELLO";
int len = line.length();
long len2 = len;
while (len2 <= index) {
    len2 *= 2;
}
while (len2 > len) {
    long lenhalf = len2 / 2;
    if (index >= lenhalf) {
        index -= lenhalf;
        index -= 1;
        if (index < 0) {
            index += lenhalf;
        }
    }
    len2 = lenhalf;
}

System.out.println(line.charAt((int)index));
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What I guess is killing you is all of the String concatenations you're doing in `buildString`.  You can cut it down to this:

```
public static String buildString(String str){
    return str.charAt(str.length()-1) + str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
}
```

Comment: You're right! The runtime was decreased by a lot! Is there anything else?

Comment: The program is supposed to be able to handle an index with the bounds of index <= 10^18. Even with this, the program can't handle that big of a number.

Comment: In this case, you need to look for an algorithm that doesn't involve concatenating the string to its rotation.  No system is going to be able to handle a 1-exabyte string.  (But that's outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: Do you have an idea as to what type of algorithm that would be?